# What are the stopwords in Tamil language?

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, tamil, stopwords

What are some of the stopwords in Tamil. The ones I could come up with were 'வது', 'ஆம்'.

Comment: https://tdil-dc.in/index.php?option=com_download&task=showresourceDetails&toolid=1641&lang=en has a downloadable list of what is alleged to be 185 stop words for Tamil. I cannot attest to its quality, but the organization seems vaguely credible. The download link requires you to register; I have not attempted to proceed past that point.

Comment: Ah, I have tried this before. This organization requires you to send a fax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the most frequent words in Tamil and make, e.g., the 50 most frequent words your stopwords.

List of the 50 most frequent words for many languages are available from the *Wortschatz* portal at Leipzig University, here is a direct links to [2017's TOP 50 words for Tamil](http://cls.corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/tam_community_2017/3.2.1_The%20Most%20Frequent%2050%20Words.html).

Comment: This seems a bit crude. Doing some statistics on the frequency distribution and/or checking with an informant who can read the language seem like obvious and not particularly sophisticated improvement ideas, though it is of course possible that they won't change the end result. 50 seems pretty low for a completely arbitrary number to pick for this purpose.

Comment: I agree with @tripleee the list contains words for government and the name of a city.

Comment: The Wortschatz collection happens to make the top-50 available as a separate download by default; but if you speak the language, you could probably download the full corpus and pick out good candidates from something similar (top-200, top-500? This also depends on orthographical conventions of the language etc).

Comment: @tripleee thank you! I am trying to do something of that sort. Do you think using a tf-idf score would help?

Comment: Just the IDF is probably sufficient already actually.